# Angular 2 component with sticky header & footer and dynamic content height

Tags: css, responsive-design, sticky-footer

I'm trying to build a component with sticky header and footer, while the content height is dynamic. I tried to use the FIDDLE example (at the bottom of this post), but the behavior is not the same. When I resize the screen, the window just run over the footer/header.

This is what I'm trying to achieve:
[image: Illustration of what I'm trying to achieve]

The FIDDLE code example:
http://jsfiddle.net/PGC7D/18/

```
    html,body
{
    height: 100%;
}
header,footer,div
{
   width: 100%; 
}
.container
{
    height: 100%;
    background: pink;
    margin: -64px 0 -30px;
    padding: 64px 0 30px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#content {
    overflow:auto;
    height:100%;
}
.block
{
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
}
header
{
    height: 64px;
    background: purple;
    position: relative;
    z-index:1;
}
footer
{
    height: 30px;
    background: gray;
    position: relative;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: Consider using flex display, which is way easier to use than playing on margins.

Comment: check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dem381rg/16/

Comment: This fiddle is not answering my needs. The footer and the header are not sticky.